# django - show the length of a queryset in a template

Tags: django

In my html file, how can I output the size of the queryset that I am using (for my debugging purposes)

I've tried

```
{{ len(some_queryset) }}
```

but that didn't work. What is the format?

Comment: There is a filter called `length` to call len() on anything. `{{ any_iterable|length }}`

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita so for this you'd used `some_queryset.all|length` ?  Is this optimum in terms of the SQL generated?  The `some_queryset.count` uses `SELECT COUNT(*)`... instead of selecting all the model fields.  I don't know how significant this is in terms of performance, I guess for something with a large query_set this could be significant?

Comment: @AJP yes. If you are ONLY getting the count, then do some_queryset.count. If it's already evaluated anyways, |length could save you a db hit.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Give `{{ some_queryset.count }}` a try.

This is better than using len (which could be invoked with `{{ some_queryset.__len__ }}`) because it optimizes the SQL generated in the background to only retrieve the number of records instead of the records themselves.

Comment: How about the filter "length"? Is it the same? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#length

Comment: is not the same! you should indeed use length, check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18578147/267719

Comment: as of now django does not allow `__len__` in templates.

Comment: FYI each successive call to `{{ some_queryset.count }}` in the template, will issue another DB call. if this is a value you'll display more than once, store the value in the view and pass it to the template.

Comment: 'MyModel' object has no attribute 'count'

Answer (score 35):

`some_queryset.count()` or `{{some_queryset.count}}` in your template.

dont use `len`, it is much less efficient. The database should be doing that work. See the documentation about [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count).

However, taking buffer's advice into account, if you are planning to iterate over the records anyway, you might as well use `len` which will involve resolving the queryset and making the resulting rows resident in main memory - this wont go to waste because you will visit these rows anyway. It might actually be faster, depending on db connection latency, but you should always measure.

Comment: `dont use len, it is much less efficient` : True, unless you are going to iterate over your queryset anyway. In that case, prefer `len` over `count`. [Read More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327036/count-vs-len-on-a-django-queryset)

Answer (score 16):

Just to highlight @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita comment above as a separate answer:

> There is a filter called `length` to call `len()` on anything.

So you could use:

```
{{ some_queryset|length }}
```

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is not entirely correct. Whether you should use len() (or the length-filter in a template) vs count() depends on your use case.

If the **QuerySet only exists to count the amount of rows**, use count().

If the **QuerySet is used elsewhere**, i.e. in a loop, use len() or |length. Using count() here would issue another SELECT-query to count the rows, while len() simply counts the amount of cached results in the QuerySet.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count):

> Note that if you want the number of items in a QuerySet and are also retrieving model instances from it (for example, by iterating over it), it’s probably more efficient to use len(queryset) which won’t cause an extra database query like count() would.

Although it seems that with related objects that you have already eager-loaded using prefetch_related(), you can safely use count() and Django will be smart enough to use the cached data instead of doing another SELECT-query.