# Using Django ----If there are more than 1 record then displaying it and if there is only 1 record then i am deleting it

Tags: python, django

What my problem is this code is displaying records whether there is 1 record or many...But i want to delete if there is 1 record....
Any advise for good code writing is obliged....

Here is my view

def delete(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST)

```
searched_data = Information.objects.filter(name="full_name").count()

d_data = None

if form.is_valid():
    if (searched_data == 1):
        d_data = Information.objects.filter(name= form.cleaned_data.get('full_name')).delete()
    else:
        d_data = Information.objects.filter(name=form.cleaned_data.get('full_name'))


context = {
    'form': form,
    'd_data': d_data,

}

return render(request, 'delete.html', context)
```

Comment: don't you mean `searched_data = Information.objects.filter(name=form.cleaned_data.get('full_name')).count()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do anything unless the form is valid:

```
if form.is_valid():
    d_data = Information.objects.filter(name=form.cleaned_data.get('full_name'))

    if len(d_data) == 1:
        d_data.delete()
        d_data = None
else:
    d_data = None

context = {
    'form': form,
    'd_data': d_data,
}

return render(request, 'delete.html', context)
```

Note: I set `d_data` to `None` after it's been deleted.

On wheter to use `d_data.count()` or `len(d_data)`, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327036/count-vs-len-on-a-django-queryset)