# Count vs len on a Django QuerySet when some results are filtered

Tags: django, django-models

A more general version of my question has already beek asked: [Count vs len on a Django QuerySet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327036/count-vs-len-on-a-django-queryset)

My case is a bit different, though. It starts with something like this:

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(foo=bar)
```

To get `error_message_count` and `other_message_count`, which is better?

```
error_message_count = len(message for message in messages if message.is_error)
other_message_count = len(messages) - error_message_count
```

or:

```
error_message_count = messages.filter(is_error = True).count()
other_message_count = messages.count() - error_message_count
```

or even:

```
error_message_count = messages.filter(is_error = True).count()
other_message_count = messages.filter(is_error = False).count()
```

I suspect that the first solution boils down to only one query, and the others in two. But perhaps Django and/or the DBMS make one of the second two more efficient?

I'll accept 'profile it' as an answer, but I wonder if any of these solutions are considered best practice.

Comment: Are you using those requested messages afterwards, or just want to get two numbers and that's it? How many messages are expected to be in the  original filtered list (tens, thousands)? What is the expected ratio of errors in the list?

Comment: Good questions, but I'm actually not sure about the answers. The numbers are for a status icon at the top of the page; the user may click it to view the messages, or ignore it. I'm not sure about the number of messages, but I'd be surprised if there are more than several dozen (so in my case, this question is more about style than performance, but somebody might have the same question for a very different application some day). I'm also not sure about the proportion that will be errors; the user would hope it's very small, but it actually depends on the quality of a third party's data.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if you retrieve all of the objects and check one by one for a boolean, it is not good way because you do it by using python which uses memory.
On the other hand, 'count' is executed in database and you don't have to get all of the rows for just checking one boolean. Therefore, I think good way is the middle one.

```
error_message_count = messages.filter(is_error = True).count()
other_message_count = messages.count() - error_message_count
```

Also, when you defined 'messages', it is a queryset but it is not executed in db until you need it which uses lazy evaluation. So, If you use a for loop for that queryset, it'll execute it directly. But if you add another filter for the desired boolean, It'll only update the database query. That's why it's better for performance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any of the three methods result in two queries. I expect the query would get executed when the `messages` object is created, and the result cached for the life of that object. (I'd be surprised and deeply disappointed in Django if the generator function reexecuted the query for each iteration!) But I think you're right that it's fair to expect the DB server to be tuned to filter the errors more efficiently than code on the client. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't execute the query for each iteration. But main thing is that if you can do it in database, do it there. If there is no way, then consider pulling all the information and iterate it. Therefore, doing the count function uses count in database and executes really fast. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

To decide between these :

```
error_message_count = len(message for message in messages if message.is_error)
other_message_count = len(messages) - error_message_count
```

or:

```
error_message_count = messages.filter(is_error = True).count()
other_message_count = messages.count() - error_message_count
```

there are some important factors that need to be considered i.e. do you have an index on `is_error`, what's the size of `messages` table and how many `+ve` / `-ve` matches do you expect. Unfortunately, `profile-it` will indeed give you a clear picture. If your table size is small (e.g. few thousand entries, it doesn't matter). If it's of the order of millions of entries, it should be fairly easy to get a clear picture with a profile.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, I should index the is_error column. Thanks for the reminder. ☺