# Django ORM datetime __range field lookup not filtering properly

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a simple query where I retrieve all the rows from the current date's 12 AM to current time.

```
time_now = datetime.now()
time_passed = time_now.hour * 60 + time_now.minute
a = (datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=time_passed))
b = datetime.now()
result_inwardCount = MYmsEvents.objects.all().filter(recorded_at__range=[a, b],event='In-ward')
print(result_inwardCount.query)
print(len(result_inwardCount))
```

Now when I print the query, it gives me this :

```
SELECT "m_yms_events"."id", "m_yms_events"."vin", "m_yms_events"."event", "m_yms_events"."location", "m_yms_events"."recorded_at", "m_yms_events"."sys_id", "m_yms_events"."x", "m_yms_events"."y", "m_yms_events"."last_updated" FROM "m_yms_events" WHERE ("m_yms_events"."event" = In-ward AND "m_yms_events"."recorded_at" BETWEEN 2021-05-19 00:00:37+05:30 AND 2021-05-19 16:49:37+05:30)
```

This gives me `0` results. When I run the same query in `pgAdmin` it gives me `41` rows.
Below is the query after adding the apostrophie  :

```
SELECT "m_yms_events"."id", "m_yms_events"."vin", "m_yms_events"."event", "m_yms_events"."location", "m_yms_events"."recorded_at", "m_yms_events"."sys_id", "m_yms_events"."x", "m_yms_events"."y", "m_yms_events"."last_updated" FROM "m_yms_events" WHERE ("m_yms_events"."event" = 'In-ward' AND "m_yms_events"."recorded_at" BETWEEN '2021-05-19 00:00:37+05:30' AND '2021-05-19 16:49:37+05:30')
```

The timezone in Postgres is `IST`, so is the timezone on to the server.

[image]

Comment: Just one extra tip. `print(len(result_inwardCount))` should be `print(result_inwardCount).count()`. It is faster and better. You can learn why here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327036/count-vs-len-on-a-django-queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Django `__range` field lookup is used directly with `datetimes` as you can see in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#range).

This is a simple working example:

```py
import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

In your specific case, just remove the part of your code that is transforming your `datetimes` to `strings` (`.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`):

```py
a = (datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=time_passed))
b = datetime.now()
result_inwardCount = MYmsEvents.objects.all().filter(recorded_at__range=[a, b], event='In-ward')
```

Comment: Initially I did that only i.e I didn't convert it to the string. I think I will edit that in question itself. The issue remains the same. I will like to point out one piece of information i.e the `recorded_at` field is defined as `recorded_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),`