# Implement Recursive function to check whether a model has child or not

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement a recursive function that will check if an object has child with the parent id. If has than it will add the child to the list and will recursively call the function to check if newly added child has further children.

**My Current Code that works fine as expected:**

```
    def get_nav_items(self, instance):
        
        childs = []
        items = Content.objects.filter(parent_id=instance)

        for item in items:
            childs.append(item)

        for item in items:
            ch = Content.objects.filter(parent_id=item)
            if ch.count() > 0:
                for c in ch:
                    childs.append(c)
        menu_objecs = []
        for item in childs:
            menu_objecs.append(ContentNevItemSerializer(item).data)
            
        return menu_objecs
```

**The method that isn't returning any result now:**

```
    def extract_item(self, nav_obj, nav_list = []):
        cont = Content.objects.filter(parent_id=nav_obj)

        if len(cont) == 0:
            return nav_list
        
        else:
            for ct in cont:
                self.extract_item(ct, nav_list)
            # nav_list.append(cont)
            return nav_list
```

Comment: Note that you should prefer count() over len() in a queryset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327036/count-vs-len-on-a-django-queryset But the `if len(cont) == 0:` step may not even be necessary - if the queryset has 0 elements, then a loop will do 0 iterations, which is the same as not looping at all.

Comment: `nav_list = []` Remember to [avoid mutable defaults](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) in functions. The same list will be re-used between calls to the same page, including the old elements, which is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, nav_list = [] was causing returing older data. That's why I had to modify function and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recursive version of checking children of django query objects.

The trick was to send a blank list through the parameter and check if the queryset has object more than zero. If the result is zero than return the passed list.

However, if there is object then it would add each objects to the list and recursively call the function and finally return the complete list.

**NB:** checking the object with `len()` will lead the queryset to re-check the database. Instead since django caches the ORM result therefore, `count()` will use the cache and calculate already received result.

```
    def extract_item(self, nav_obj, nav_list: list):
        """
        Recursively call and check if there is any child available.
        """
        cont = Content.objects.filter(parent_id=nav_obj)
        if len(cont) == 0:
            return nav_list
        else:
            for ct in cont:
                nav_list.append(ct)
                self.extract_item(ct, nav_list)
            return nav_list

    def get_nav_items(self, instance):
        """
        Get all the children for the model object
        """
        childs = self.extract_item(instance, [])
        menu_objecs = []
        for item in childs:
            menu_objecs.append(ContentNevItemSerializer(item).data)
        return menu_objecs
```