# Is using any with a QuerySet unoptimal?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Many times, one needs to check if there is at least one element inside a `QuerySet`. Mostly, I use [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists):

```
if queryset.exists():
   ...
```

However, I've seen colleagues using python's [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
if any(queryset):
   ...
```

**Is using python's `any` function unoptimal?**

My intuition tells me that this is a similar dilemma to one [between using `count` and `len`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327036/count-vs-len-on-a-django-queryset): `any` will iterate through the `QuerySet` and, therefore, will need to evaluate it. In a case where we will use the `QuerySet` items, this doesn't create any slowdowns. However, if we need just to check if any pieces of data that satisfy a query exist, this might load data that we do not need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is using python's any function unoptimal?

The most Pythonic way would be:

```
if queryset:
    # …
```

Indeed, a `QuerySet` has *truthiness* `True` if it contains at least one item, and `False` otherwise.

In case you later want to enumerate over the queryset (with a `for` loop for example), it will load the items in the cache if you check its truthiness, so for example:

```
if queryset:
    for item in queryset:
        # …
```

will only make *one* query to the database: one that will fetch all items when you check the `if queryset`, and then later you can reuse that cache without making a second query.

In case you do *not* consume the queryset later in the process, then you can work with a [**`.exists()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists): this will *not* load records in memory, but only make a query to check if at least one such record exists, this is thus less expensive in terms of bandwidth between the application and the database. If you however have to consume the queryset later, using `.exists()` is *not* a good idea, since then we make two queries.

Using `any(queryset)` however is non-sensical: you can check if a queryset contains elements by its truthiness, so using `any()` will usually only make that check *slightly* less efficient.