# Django template length filter broken for _set?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I use `|length` filter in my templates to display the recordcount of my objects, however I'm currently forced to use `.count` since it seems that using the filter against a related set doesn't work! The following

```
{{ myobject.retatedObject_set.all|length }}
```

prints ***literally***:

```
{{ myobject.retatedObject_set.all|length }}
```

And this:

```
{{ myobject.retatedObject_set.all.count }}
```

returns the expected result...

**BUT**: count() generates an extra SQL query, which is why I always use |length filter which doesn't! (see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18578147/267719 to question [django - show the length of a queryset in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10695322/267719))

Can this be considered a bug in the Django template engine? How can I avoid the extra query?

**EDIT:**

After an hard debug I realized that the problem was the use of the django-debug-toolbar (which prints in its panels each filter used as normal strings) plus the use of AngularJS (which has the same syntax for its templates). I solved by reconfiguring AngularJS to use different symbols:

```
config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});
```

Comment: Can you use any filters? I guess you could try setting `DEBUG` and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` to true in your settings and see if any weird errors show up.

Comment: yes, other filters are ok (for example I use |date as usual to display formatted dates) and I have debug and template_debug turned on