# How do I display the number of object returned from a query

Tags: django

I want to display the number of objects returned from query search. I have tried

```
 {{ p.count }} and {{ Post.count }}
```

Here is my post_list.html. I have read other posts that use those methods and they do not work for me. I know I am missing something.

```
   {% extends 'posts/base.html' %}

    {% block content %}



    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

        <form method="get" action=" ">
            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}"/>
            <input type="submit" value=" search"/>
        </form>

        <a href="{% url 'posts:create'  %}">create</a>
    {% for p in queryset %}

        <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12 "> <!-- i like col-sm-6 -->
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        {% if p.image %}
                        <img src='{{ p.image.url }}' class="img-responsive" />
                        {% endif %}
                      <!--<img src="..." alt="...">-->
                      <div class="caption">
                          {% if p.draft %} <h3>Staff Only: Draft</h3> {%  if p.publish > today %}<h3>Staff Only: Future Post</h3>  {% endif  %}
                          {% endif %}
                        <h3><a href='{{ p.get_absolute_url}}'>{{p.title}}</a> <small>{{p.publish | timesince }} </small> </h3>
                          {% if p.user.get_full_name %}<p>Author: {{  p.user.get_full_name  }}</p>{% endif %}
                        <p>{{p.content | truncatechars:30}}</p>
                        <p><a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url}}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a>

                            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <a href='{% url "posts:update" p.slug %}' class="btn btn-default" role="button">edit</a>
                            <a href='{% url "posts:delete" p.id %}' class="btn btn-danger" role="button">delete</a>
                            {% endif %}

                        </p>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            <hr>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}

        <div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if queryset.has_previous %}
                <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.previous_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}

            <span class="current">
                Page {{ queryset.number }} of {{ queryset.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>

            {% if queryset.has_next %}
                <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.next_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>

    </div>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do `count` on a single object `p`, because there's no count for that. Only queryset has `count` method, so do:

```
{{ queryset.count }}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. the answer posted above does, but not quite how I want it. I'm using pagination. So {{ query|length }} only returns the the max amount of objects on the first page of the pagination but not all the objects in total

Comment: Then your `queryset` is not really a queryset but something object related to pagination. If you use `{{ queryset|length }}`, as long as your `queryset` object is an interable(list, tuple, dict), it will work. `count` is more efficient because it calls db operation `count(*)` directly on queryset, but `length` would do something like `len(queryset)` and will evaluate the whole queryset. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695322/django-show-the-length-of-a-queryset-in-a-view

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the the built-in filter [`length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#length)

> Returns the length of the value. This works for both strings and lists.

You can use it within your template to get the length of any object

```
{{ queryset|length }}
```

Comment: Thanks @Suever I'm using pagination. So {{ query|length }} only returns the the max amount of objects on the first page of the pagination but not all the objects in total