# Showing a total of items created in a Django model

Tags: django

My Django project contains a task manager with Projects and Tasks, I have generic list page showing a list of all projects with information on their total tasks:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'projects/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'project_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return 10 projects."""
        return Project.objects.order_by('is_complete')[:10]
```

I would like to display on my list page the total number of added projects and tasks, but I'm unsure how I should go about this. All my current work has been around listing the number of tasks that are included i each project, but now I want a total - should I add this as a new View? For example, I tried adding this to the view above:

```
def total_projects(self):
    return Project.objects.count()
```

Then calling `{{ project_list.total_projects }}` on my template, but it doesn't return anything.

Is Views the correct place to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's more common to put function definitions in the Model class (`Project`, from the looks of it), and add the `@property` tag above the function.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ''' definitions and stuff '''

    @property
    def total_projects(self): # etc...
```

As for your specific case, you could forego the function altogether and just use `{{ project_list.count }}` or `{{ project_list|length }}` in your template.

A note about `count` vs `length` from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#s-count):

> A count() call performs a SELECT COUNT(*) behind the scenes, so you
>   should always use count() rather than loading all of the record into
>   Python objects and calling len() on the result (unless you need to
>   load the objects into memory anyway, in which case len() will be
>   faster).
>
> Note that if you want the number of items in a QuerySet and are also
>   retrieving model instances from it (for example, by iterating over
>   it), it’s probably more efficient to use len(queryset) which won’t
>   cause an extra database query like count() would.

So use the correct one for your usage.

Also, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14327086/3927528) and the below comment from @djangomachine, `length` may not always return the same number of records as `count`. If accuracy is important it may be better to use `count` regardless of the above case.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, I'll read up on @property tag! I wasn't aware of the |length property, but it worked perfectly!

Comment: {{ project_list|length }} computes the number of instances in the project_list queryset, which may not be the same as Project.objects.all().  Additionally, I believe it's better to use {{ project_list.count }} rather than {{ project_list|length }} as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695322/django-show-the-length-of-a-queryset-in-a-template

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @djangomachine, I hadn't seen that. I updated my answer with some info from the Django docs

Answer (score 2):

> All by current work has been around listing the number of tasks that are included i each project, but now I want a total - should I add this as a new View?

It depends. If you just want to show the total number of projects and tasks with the first 10 completed projects in the database (which is what your `get_queryset` method does, be careful), I would go and do all of it in the same view (it would be useless to make a new view only to show some numbers, and that isn't the purpose of `ListView` IMO).

On the other hand, you're calling a class's instance method (`total_projects`) from a model's instance. That method doesn't exists on the model, and when an attribute/method doesn't exists in an object when calling it in a template, you just get nothing. Based on the previous paragraph, I would set it in the view's context using [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    data["total_projects"] = Projects.objects.count()
    # I'm assuming you only need the whole number of tasks with no separation
    data["total_tasks"] = Task.objects.count()

    return data
```

Finally, you can edit your `get_queryset` method and make it be an [instance attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects) (if you want it to be cleaner and you can handle the filtering with no additional code):

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Project.objects.order_by('is_complete')[:10]
```

Comment: Thank you - how would I access the contents of `data` from my template?

Comment: Just like you access the context in normal views, ``{{ total_projects }}``.